# Is it natural and corect to use the adjective "relevant" to describe someone who is right for a task?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, adjectives

Can you please tell me if it is natural and corect to use the adjective "relevent" to describe someone who is right for a task? For example:

> You can let me know what kind of problem you have with your software and I'll direct it to the **relevant** specialist.

I've looked the word up in online dictionaries but wasn't able to find sentences where it was used that way.

Regardless of whether it was used naturally or not, I'd like to have other alternatives to replace *relevant* with please.

Comment: "the/an appropriate", "a suitable"

Comment: Your sentence is perfectly natural, but _relevant_ means _related to the subject in question_ rather than _the right one for the task_.

Comment: What @KateBunting said is the "literal" meaning of ***relevant***, but in practice it's routinely used in line with this definition from Cambridge: ***correct or suitable for a particular purpose***.